# How to grouping variable and create multidimensional array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a list of variable inside array like this :

- **a = mango**
- **b = potato**
- **c = peach**
- **d = grape**
- **a = mango, potato**
- **a = potato, banana**

how to create array in jquery and concat same variable and remove duplicate data when it founds in same variable?

expected results :

**[b=> "potato", c => "peach",d=>"grape", a=>"mango, potato,banana" ]**

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show your array ?

Comment: actually the question above just simple description. i using x= $("form").serializeArray(); to create array and the duplicate values come from checkbox

Answer (score 0):

This function give like that {b=> "potato", c => "peach",d=>"grape", a=>["mango", "potato","banana"]}

> $(function () {
>         $('#btnClick').click( function(){
>
> ```
>     var array={};
>     var a =[];        
>     a.push("mango")
>     a.push("apple")
>     a.push("mango")
>
>     a = $.unique(a);
>     var val = "";
>     for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
>       val += a[i] + ",";
>     }
>     val = val.slice(0, -1) //remove last comma
>     alert(val);       array.a=a;      array.b="potato";       array.c="peach";        array.d="grape";     });
> });
> ```

Comment: thanks visnu, i used x=$("form").serializeArray(); to generate array from my form, and some of data come form checkbox need to be concatenated like the "a" variables i ilustrated above. Currently i used  $.each(x, function(i, field){ }); to do loop and rebuild array.

Comment: Ok.Is this helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery/JavaScript doesn't allow string key values for arrays, but the widely accepted workaround is to create an object (which still allows you to use bracket notation). So instead of
`arr = [b=> "potato", c => "peach",d=>"grape", a=>"mango, potato,banana" ]`
you can do
`arr = { 'b': "potato", 'c': "peach", 'd': "grape", 'a': "mango"};`
Since it's an object, you must specify a property name for the `potato` and `banana` that you have at the end.

In JavaScript, you'll be able to access "peach" as both `arr.c` and `arr['c']`.

One downfall of this method is that you lose some native features of arrays, such as the `.length` property, and a variety of array functions.

Let me know if that helps, or if you have any questions :)